# What can be implied from loss function that its regularizer needs large coefficient

Tags: regularization, loss-functions

I run loss function with l1-norm as [regularizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) for source separation.

$min\sum_{i=1}^{n} V(f(x_{i}), y_{i}) + \lambda R(f)$

I varied the coefficient ($\lambda$) from 0 to 1e14. The results ($\frac{\text{true source activation}}{\text{false source activation}}$ and error result calculated from loss function) do not appear to have the effect from l1-norm until $\lambda$ is very large (1e8). What can I imply from this observation?

[image]